# Actualizar cantidad de un modelo desde otro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Estoy trabajando en proyecto en donde existe un **Stock principal de Bidons (Bidones)**, pero me gustaría editar el Stock principal de este ***cuando se ocupe ese Stock en otro modelo***, por ejemplo cuando se realiza una compra de un producto principal y este Stock se vaya restando con el que ingrese.

Los modelos son:

**Compra**

```
class Compra < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bidon #De acá recogemos el Stock principal
end
```

**Bidon**

```
class Bidon < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :compras
end
```

En el modelo **compras** tengo acceso al **:bidon_id**, puedo seleccionar el bidón, pero la cantidad la estoy guardando con otro campo llamado: :cantidad_bidones. El nombre del campo en el modelo **Bidons** se llama solamente **:cantidad** y pensabas que en el controlador **compras_controller** podría restar la **:cantidad_bidones** con la **:cantidad** del modelo **Bidons** para lograr el descuento del Stock Principal al crear la compra. Esto lo voy a hacer con otros modulos, por ello necesito alguna orientación por favor.

**compras_controller.rb**

```
 def new
    @compra = Compra.new
    @bidons = Bidon.all.map{ |b| [b.id] }
  end

 def create
    @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)
    @compra.bidon_id = params[:bidon_id]
end

   private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_compra
      @compra = Compra.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def compra_params
      params.require(:compra).permit(:proveedor_id, :cantidad_bidones, :calibradas, :calibre, :tipo, :bidon_id)
    end
end
```

En el formulario de compras tengo lo siguiente:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cantidad_bidones %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :cantidad_bidones %>
  </div>
      <div class="field">
      <%= select_tag(:bidon_id, options_for_select(@bidons), :prompt => "Seleccione los Bidones") %>
    </div>
```

Solamente esa sería mi consulta, como modificar los datos ya existentes en el modelo Bidons en este caso **:cantidad**

Comment: Podrías poner la parte del schema.rb que corresponden al modelo Compra y Stock? Estoy casi seguro que esa lógica debe ir en el modelo, pero para poder darte un buen ejemplo tendría que ver todos los attributos

Comment: No entendi muy bien tu pregunta, como quieres modificar :cantidad en el modelo bidons, le quieres asignar el mismo valor que tiene :cantidad_bidones? que operacion deseas realizar ahi?

Comment: Existe un área de producción, de ventas, de compras, stock (bidones ya con el producto) si utilizo un bidon en el area de stock, osea realizo una venta a un cliente con el producto, se deben descontar la cantidad de bidones utilizados y así en todos las otras áreas, comprobar si los bidones se devolvieron, manteniendo un registro al ingresarlos nuevamente, pero siempre utilizando una cantidad que sea global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toda la lógica de tu aplicación siempre ira en los modelos. Ya que Ruby On Rails es un framework orientado al patron MVC modelo vista controlador. La solucion de tener un servisio no es la correcta ya que el framework no trabaja de esa manera. Los servicios se usan pero para desarrollo en java.

Entonces la solución mas optima y con mejores practicas, es usar callbacks
aquí esta la documentación completa de esto para que la leas.
[Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)
Por lo cual en tu modelo de compras debes de tener un callback

> after_save

Entonces esto lo que aria es que cada que guardes un registro de compra automáticamente dispare un método que se ejecutara solo después que se guarde la compra.

Te quedaria de esta forma

```
class Bidon
  has_many :compras
end

class Compra
  after_save :descontar_bidones

  belongs_to :bidon

  private
  # Este es un metodo que se disparara automaticamente despues que se guarde una compra
  # self.bidon llama a la relacion belongs_to que esta arriba y le descuenta la cantidad comprada este es un campo de la tabla compra.
  # luego se guarda el objeto relacionado
  def descontar_bidones
    self.bidon.existencias -= self.cantidad_comprada
    self.bidon.save
  end
end
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: ¿Como podría evitar que guardar  la cantidad existente, esta compruebe que no quedan bidones? ya que al seguir realizando compras, la cantidad de los bidones queda en -120 por ejemplo. Me gustaría que me diga "No quedan bidones" o que en el select no aparezcan los bidones que están presentes si estos no superar la cantidad mayor a 0.

Answer (score 3):

Estoy de acuerdo con los comentarios que has recibido. Es difícil saber que lógica estás implementando, y da la sensación de que no es correcta. Sin embargo, si estás seguro de tu implementación, lo que buscas podría ser algo así:

```
 def create
  @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)
  @bidon = Bidon.find(params[:bidon_id])
  @compra.bidon = @bidon

  @bidon.cantidad -= @compra.cantidad_bidones

  #responde a la petición como veas conveniente
end
```

Sin embargo esto se considera mucho lógica para un controlador. En su lugar, yo te aconsejaría que usases un servicio.

/app/servicios/servicio_compra.rb

```
class ServicioCompra
  attr_accessor :compra, :bidon

  def initialize(compra, bidon)
    @compra = compra
    @bidon = bidon
  end

  def realizar_compra
    compra.bidon = bidon
    bidon.cantidad -= compra.cantidad_bidones

    compra.save && bidon.save
  end
end
```

Desde el controlador tendrías que llamar a este servicio:

```
 def create
  @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)
  @bidon = Bidon.find(params[:bidon_id])

  ServicioCompra.new(compra, bidon).realizar_compra

  #responde a la petición como veas conveniente
end
```

El código todavía se podría mejorar, pero creo que este camino sería el correcto